# Getting error in AWS toolkit for Visual Studio: Error loading AWS profile

Tags: aws-sdk-net

I have installed AWS SDK toolkit for VS 2017. It was working fine. All of a sudden since few days back i am getting error "Error loading AWS profiles: Method not found:'Amazon.Runtime.TcpKeepAlive Amazon.Runtime.ClientConfig.get_TcpKeepAlive()"

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling the toolkit, also i tried installing it on other machine with VS 2013, but both giving same error.

[image]
Is it problem with toolkit or anything changed on AWS side?

I have Windows 10 with latest updates.
VS2017 community edition
VS2013 community edition

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I found the old installer of AWS Extension for VS2017 on my machine. it is v1.14.2.0, and it is working fine.

Answer (score 2):

It is mostly caused an older version of AWSSDK.core that has already been added to GAC and is forcing your VS to use an older version of AWSSDK.core.dll.

After uninstalling all the other/previous versions of AWSSDK libraries (AWSSDK.S3.dll etc) from GAC solved the problem for me.

Also installing the latest AWSSDK.core.dll to GAC can work.

Hope this info helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Solution here that worked for me :
https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/issues/1138

I have resolved this issue by uninstalling the latest one and installing this previous stable version of aws toolbar from visual studio update website(exact link https://aws.amazon.com/visualstudio where previous vsix downloaded).. if you cannot find the previous version here I added to my drive you can download.. https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Fkrxmv-dM8fwGDjNqse1Ssdm0k3YYbcH

Once you install old extention, be sure to disable auto update extension in VS.